# OBS doesnt work with amdgpu-pro drivers, but i need it in resolve

Tags: amd-graphics, obs-studio

I am using Pop OS 21.04 and im a youtuber. I tend to use kdenlive for my video editing, but for some clips, I need davinci resolve. Davinci resolve seems to require amdgpu-pro drivers, but those are only availible for Ubuntu LTS releases. But I saw a Blender article about installing those on Pop OS and that worked with resolve, but now OBS, my only screen capture program, doesnt work because of gpu drivers. What can I do?

Thanks
Irsu85

Comment: Are you explicitly saying OBS was working and now it is not working after you installed amdgpu-pro drivers? When you say "with resolve" I am assuming you are talking about POPOSs package manager (I am not familiar with POPos)

Comment: no, with resolve, I mean, Davinci resolve, and I installed OBS after I installed amdgpu-pro

Comment: Have you searched the web? I see plenty of duscussion about small issues with OBS and amdgpu-pro drivers. (e.g. the top five results in google are links to forum / bug reports when I query obs amdgpu-pro).

Comment: I have, but not a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I tried installing the APT version of OBS instead of the flatpak version I had before. Xcomposite does bug, but I don't use that very often, and the rest seems to work. Thanks everyone for helping me